# Accessing dictionary item returned by function with Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2

Consider the below lookup being assigned to a variable:

```yaml
my_var: "{{ lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var') }}"
```

The above lookup returns a dictionary with the following data:

```json
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

How would I access the value of `key1` and assign it to `my_var`? I tried these variations:

```yaml
my_var: "{{ lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var').key1 }}"

my_var: "{{ lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var')['key1'] }}"

my_var: "{{ (lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var')).key1 }}"

my_var: "{{ (lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var'))['key1'] }}"
```

All of them return null values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always keep in mind that ansible/jinja2 magically reinterprets a previously stored yaml/json string representations into lists/dicts. This is what happened when you debugged your lookup content.

You stored your value `my/var` in consul as a json **string** representation of a dictionary containing two keys.

This will be even clearer if you directly check the type of value you get from the lookup:

```yaml
- name: Check the var type returned by lookup
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var') | type_debug }}"
```

which gives:

```
TASK [Check the var type returned by lookup] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "AnsibleUnsafeText"
}
```

If you want to address one of the keys of the represented dictionary directly, you have to "force" that "magic" reinterpretation of your json structure, i.e. use the `from_json` filter.

```yaml
- name: store my var
  set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ (lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var') | from_json).key1 }}"
```

Alternatively, you can go through an intermediate var which will automagically do the job for you

```yaml
- name: store my var
  vars:
    my_kv: "{{ lookup('community.general.consul_kv', 'my/var') }}"
  set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ my_kv.key1 }}"
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I had pieced together the automagical bit using two variables but was stumped about how to do it in one line.